# how to fetch latest transaction from bitcoin block chain network via node.js or c#

Tags: c#, node.js, blockchain, bitcoin

I'm new to blockchain technology, I have been playing around with bitcoin node.
I've searched all over the internet to fetch the latest transaction of the bitcoin network via programming (c#, node.js) but I didn't find any decent piece of code to do that.
**Can anyone suggest me how to do fetch the latest transaction of bitcoin network**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axIoq.png) I did the same with Socket.io just looking for an alternate solution

Comment: Nobody write code for you, you should find the way, If you are facing any challenge then put your query with the code on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this api:

```
https://blockchain.info/address/$hash_160?format=json
```

it will provide you with a list of the latest transactions.

Comment: https://blockexplorer.com/ on this website, every transaction is added at the latest. Please refer to it, To get the clear view of my question

Comment: so, if you know the address and where to go, there is no question here. You cannot expect us to write the code for you.